# Buzzing noise playing mp3 on Audiotrack on Android

Tags: android, audio, mp3, noise

i try and play an mp3 file in my SDCard for my Android emulator but all that comes out is some weird buzzing noise. I made sure the sample rate is 44.1k hz i don't know what else could be wrong

```
    if(AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC != mode && AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM != mode)
            throw new InvalidParameterException();

    String audioFilePath = "/sdcard/test.mp3";
    long fileSize = 0;
    long bytesWritten = 0;
    int bytesRead = 0;
    int bufferSize = 0;
    byte[] buffer;
    AudioTrack track;

            File audioFile = new File(audioFilePath);
            fileSize = audioFile.length();
    if(AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM == mode)
    {
            bufferSize = 8000;
    }
    else
    {// AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC
            bufferSize = (int)fileSize;
    }
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,/* this is for pcm*/ /*22050*/ /*this is for mp3*/ 44100, 
                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_DEFAULT/*AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT*/, 
                            bufferSize, mode);
    // in stream mode, 
    //   1. start track playback
    //   2. write data to track
    if(AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM == mode)
            track.play(); 
    FileInputStream audioStream = null;
    try {
                    audioStream = new FileInputStream(audioFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

    while(bytesWritten < fileSize)
    {
            try {
                    bytesRead = audioStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            bytesWritten += track.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    // in static mode,
    //   1. write data to track
    //   2. start track playback
    if(AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC == mode)
            track.play();
```

Answer (score 3):

It's correct that you hear strange noise, since you need to decode the MP3 first before
you feed it to an AudioTrack! AudioTrack only plays raw PCM audio.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `android.media.MediaPlayer` to play mp3 audio file